# Am I repeating myself too much in my code?

Tags: javascript

I'm in the process of learning JavaScript and wrote this function which simply hides an element such as the navbar on scroll, however, the only way I could think of writing this without looking for an answer online was like below:

```js
let scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
const scrollDown = document.querySelector('.navbar');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    scrollPosition = window.scrollY;

    if (scrollPosition >= 600) {
        scrollDown.classList.add('is-hidden');
      scrollDown.classList.remove('is-visible');
    } else {
      scrollDown.classList.remove('is-hidden');
        scrollDown.classList.add('is-visible');
    }
});
```

I get a strong feeling that my code is not dry and I'm repeating myself and a seasoned JavaScript developer could help me if that is the case otherwise tell me that it's fine.

Comment: Do you need `scrollPosition` outside that callback?

Comment: @trincot I don't accidentally left it in there, it was commented out :)

Comment: Next time, try to post such questions on [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). That site is made for this *exact purpose* which is reviewing code, so your question would fit better there. I'd also note to see their [Help Center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) because guidelines and rules differ from site to site. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce it to two ternaries, but it's not necessarily better or more readable.

```
const predicate = (scrollPosition >= 600);
scrollDown.classList.add(predicate ? 'is-hidden' : 'is-visible');
scrollDown.classList.remove(predicate ? 'is-visible' : 'is-hidden');
```

Why do you have two different CSS rules for hidden and visible? What exactly are you trying to do? It is probably enough to just have a `.hidden` with `display: none;` that you can add or remove depending on what you want to accomplish.

Comment: You are correct about css rules i dont need 2. thank you for your help

Comment: Great! Please mark the question as answered if it's been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a two-liner solution

```
scrollDown.classList.add(scrollPosition >= 600 ? 'is-hidden' : 'is-visible');
scrollDown.classList.remove(scrollPosition >= 600 ? 'is-visible' : 'is-hidden');
```